# How to sum multi dimensional vectors of type "Any" in julia?

Tags: julia, julia-jump

```
julia> A=[]
Any[]

julia> B=[]
Any[]

julia> C=[]
Any[]

julia> push!(A,0.0)

1-element Vector{Any}:

 0.0

julia> push!(B,0.0)

1-element Vector{Any}:

 0.0

julia> push!(C,0.0)

1-element Vector{Any}:

 0.0

julia> push!(C,5.0)

2-element Vector{Any}:

 0.0
 5.0

julia> A+B+C

ERROR: DimensionMismatch("dimensions must match: a has dims (Base.OneTo(1),), b has dims (Base.OneTo(2),), mismatch at 1")
```

Comment: What should the result be? The sizes are different, so it doesn't make sense to add them.

Comment: @OscarDowson, the result will be 5 anyways, but I need to sum up different dimensioned vectors.

Comment: You want to sum the _elements_ of the vectors? That's something slightly different to summing vectors.

Comment: `sum(A)+sum(B)+sum(C)`

Answer (score 0):

All you need is `sum(A) + sum(B) + sum(C)`, as @OscarDowson points out. `sum` will reduce a multidimensional array to a single sum value, so there's no dimension mismatch when you sum the result of that.

If you have many such arrays, say:

```
julia> A = [0.0]
1-element Vector{Float64}:
 0.0

julia> B = [1.0, 2.0]
2-element Vector{Float64}:
 1.0
 2.0

julia> C = [2.0 0.0]
1×2 Matrix{Float64}:
 2.0  0.0

julia> D = [0.0 ;;; 0.0] # 3-dimensional array
1×1×2 Array{Float64, 3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 0.0

[:, :, 2] =
 0.0
```

you can also do:

```
julia> sum(sum(array) for array in (A, B, C, D))
5.0
```